# Number of ways to buy candy given a money value and candy prices

Tags: python, dynamic-programming

While trying to solve a problem at brilliant.org [Dynamic Programming: Level 4 Challenges](https://brilliant.org/practice/dynamic-programming-level-4-5-challenges/?subtopic=algorithms&chapter=dynamic-programming) I tried a simple solution of just using an array (or list) and storing the number of ways each money value can be spent. This works until the money variable goes higher than 10. At 11 it has 1 more than it should, and I cannot find out why. I imagine it is counting the same value twice, but as there are too many posibilities at this point, it is infeasible to count one by one.

I already looked at the solution, but I'd just like a hint on what I might be missing here.

EDIT: All permutations of possible solutions should also be counted.

```
money = 40
values = [1, 2, 5, 10]

def solver(money, values):
    mtx = [0 for _ in range(money+1)]

    mtx[0] = 1; mtx[1] = 1

        for i in range(2, money+1):
            for v in values:
            if i - v >= 0:
                mtx[i] += mtx[i-v]

    return mtx[-1]
```

EDIT 2: This code, posted on the solutions section of the website, gives the correct answer. I think the line "res = 1 if n == 0 else 0", when it does an "else 0", is probably where the correcting from my solution is made, but I cannot be sure

```
Candide_ = {}

def Candide(n, depth):
    "Candice's trip to the candy shop"
    if depth == 0:
        res = 1 if n == 0 else 0
    elif n == 0:
        res  = 1
    elif (n, depth) in Candide_:
       res  =  Candide_[(n, depth)]
    else:
        res = sum(Candide(m, depth - 1) for m in [n-1, n-2, n-5, n-10] if m >= 0)
        Candide_[(n, depth)] = res
    return res

print(Candide(40, 10))
```

Comment: Is there anything special about a `money` value of ten or eleven? Your *symptom* implies that there is some kind of boundary that makes the function behave different above 10.

Comment: Not that I can think of. At 10 is when all values (in this example) can start been used.

Comment: Do you get the same/similar symptom with a different values in `values` or a different list length?

Comment: With different values it's the same. With a different list length, it starts after the largest value on the list. So that's a pattern

Comment: Now I think that I should remove this +1 count when "money" goes to one more than the maximum value on "values", like money=11 when max(values)=10. But I'm still not sure how to remove this +1.

Comment: I'm not getting where you're off by 1.  `solver(11, values)` returns 220, just as it should.  What specific values do you get?

Comment: Using the code given in the solution, I find that solver(11, [1, 2, 5, 10]) should be 219. I'm also not sure why. I could post the code here, but as it is not mine I'm not sure if I should.

Comment: Got it.  The problem for me is that your posting is *not* self-contained; off-site links are generally not acceptable.  You didn't post the entire problem.  There's a limit to the quantity of candies to purchase.

Comment: Thank you. I think my problem was a reading problem.... Sorry for not posting the entire problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a limit to the quantity of candies to purchase, which you didn't include in your coding.  Your value for `money=11` is one high because you've include buying eleven one-unit candies.  This is not because the most expensive candy is 10 units; it's because you're limited to buying 10 items total.

Your solution would need to also keep track of the quantity of candies in each permutation, either directly or implicitly.  The solution given on the site (which you just posted above), implements this restriction in the recursion depth.

Comment: Actually, the permutations of the possible solutions should also be counted. So it works on this case. Sorry if I didn't make it clear before.

Comment: Ah ... no, it wasn't clear.  The classic problem is simply the combinations.  It's clear now.

Comment: Sorry about that